# Upvote Downvote interaction without login

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Apps such as FML, TWI etc that display user supplied data have the ability to upvote and downvote submissions such as "I agree", "I disagree", "like", "dislike".

Users are able to vote regardless if they are logged into the app in any means. Anonymous users can vote and it stores their vote for that post/entry.

I have no problem with incrementing the up or down votes on my server database when a public user votes but how do these applications keep track of a user's votes within their app so that they can not keep giving upvotes again and again for the same item and can also visually show which way they voted if they go into that submission again?

I won't be storing on my server which items a user has voted on and which direction the vote was as these are not registered/logged in users.

Any idea how I can implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each item must have some sort of ID right? Save that in your app along with their vote. If the ID exists in your store, don't allow them to vote, if it doesn't exists, allow them to vote.

Comment: This was what I was thinking. Yes each item has an ID, I would then have to store the ID and the direction of the vote for every vote that installation has ever made. This is the only form of data I need to store locally, what would be the best method to store it? Is it a bit excessive for NSUserDefaults? And is a local sqlite DB overboard for what would be 2 pieces of information? Perhaps a KEY:VALUE on ID:VOTE 123456:YES that way I could do a if(objectForKey:ID)

Comment: I'd use a database. Mainly because it scales quite well. And if you expecting a lot of transactions that'd be the best way to go. If it is only a few (say less than 10) NSUerDefaults would be alright.

Comment: I've got it working with a local SQLite DB based on PostID and Vote. INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE depending on the vote circumstances ie. (first vote, changing vote, removing vote). Thanks for your help. Marked as answer

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing each rated item in the app you could create a unique id for each device and store that information on your server.

Load the user id from NSUserDefaults and if it doesn't exist create a new one and save it.

```
NSString *userID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserID"];
if (!userID) {
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    userID = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userID forKey:@"UserID"];
}
```

edit: I missed the "show the user which way they voted" part. So you have to store it locally anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't need to keep track of who voted on what on the server, just what the current vote count is in both directions for that post. The context surrounding this question is more so the user can visually see they have previously voted on that post and to also stop them adding more votes. I could store locally the uniqueID of every post they have voted on and which direction they voted, though as this is only 2 small pieces of information where would be best to store it locally?

Comment: Matthias, is this what Apple recommends we use instead of the normal unique identifier? Thanks.