# Upvote Downvote without login

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, database

Apps such as FML, TWI etc that display user supplied data have the ability to upvote and downvote submissions such as "I agree", "I disagree", "like", "dislike".

Anyone is able to vote if they are logged into the app. Anonymous users can vote and it stores their vote for that post/entry.

I have two buttons, one to upvote and one to downvote. When a user presses this button I need the result to be sent to a database (SQLite) thats hosted on my web server. Then I need the app, when a user opens the app, to pull the results from my database into my app and display the results. 
How do these applications keep track of a user's votes within their app so that they can not keep giving upvotes again and again for the same item and can also visually show which way they voted if they go into that submission again?

How can I create this database and that the database is connected to my xcode project?

Any idea how I can implement this?

Thanks

Comment: The database will not be connected to the Xcode project directly - why should it? You could possibly use CoreData with a remote SQLite layer beneath it - but then again, that might overcomplicate the task. Why not using a simple web-api for the database access?

Comment: I don't have that much knowledge in using databases... What way would you recommend doing it in the easiest and best way? How would I use an web-api for the db access?

Comment: *easy* is rather subjective. For me, the easiest, most scalable and least insecure way would be using a web-api. That part I would develop using a scripting language on the server side (e.g. Ruby, Python, Perl, PHP, ...).

Comment: Seems to me you've got a design problem with conflicting goals.  This is the sort of thing you have to work out yourself.  Clearly you need to somehow attach an ID value of some sort to the "anonymous" votes.  (The way to talk to the web app is probably "REST".)

Comment: For that "anonymous" user issue, you could simply use a cookie.

Comment: Ok, but is it hard to create an web-api and then get it to work on my app with the intention I have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upvote Downvote interaction without login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850363/upvote-downvote-interaction-without-login)